# Replacing less-than sign and file with file content

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a small executable that takes a file name as input with the less-than sign :

```
small_executable < myfile.txt
```

This works perfectly.
But I would like to replace the input with the file content.
My understanding is that this should be strictly equivalent to :

```
small_executable << EOF
The content of my 
multi line file
EOF
```

However, this is not working. **Is there a difference between the two commands that I am missing?** I don't have access to the code of `small_executable`.

EDIT: I removed details about why I am doing that since it has no impact on the question.

Comment: You'd need `<< 'EOF'` and the file not to contain `EOF` lines nor NUL bytes (in bash) and the last line of the file to be delimited for it to be equivalent. Also note that in some shells including recent versions of `bash`, here-documents are not implemented with regular files (as they were in the original Bourne implementation) but as pipes which means `small_executable` won't be able to seek within it for instance.

Comment: can you give more detail about *this is not working* ? does it hang ? does it crash ? content is discarded ? not read ?

Comment: hm, but `< ` and `<<` are *shell* things, but you mention you're doing this from Python. So, where exactly does Python come into play here? By the way, no, your program does **not** take a file name as input! What you're doing with `< filename`  is telling your shell to read the file `filename` and pass it to the program as *standard input*; The program never sees the file! So, if you don't to use a file: then don't use a file. Things like `echo "stringy stuff" |  small_executable` work just as well!

Comment: @MarcusMüller
I call bash command from Python. You are right, this information was irrelevant for my question. But anyways, I am first testing the two commands from the shell. 
So I would like to understand the difference between those two commands that should pass exactly the same thing to the standard input of my program (one by opening the file and giving the content to stdin and the other by directly giving the content I give).

Comment: why would you call bash from python to call a different program? That makes no sense, call `small_executable` directly using `Popen` and pass in the input you want.